# What counts as crowd control during bossfights?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

With Patch 2.0 Some achievements were removed, some other achievements were added.

A couple of these new achievements are basically "Kill boss X without using crowd control".

What counts as crowd control? Does cold damage(wich slows) counts as crowd control? Or is it aimed for stuns or specific skills such as slow time?

Comment: Cold doesn't count, I got the achievements while using Frozen Orb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crowd control spells are those which mass-stun/freeze or have specific debuffing, distracting or confusing the opponents to slip out of tight circumstances.
If you use these, you cannot get the achievement. Slowing, chilling or burning effects do not count. For example, Slow Time can be used without limitation.

Some that I know of:

#### Barbarian:

- Ignore Pain
- Ground Stomp

#### Wizard

- Frost Nova
- Diamond Skin

#### Monk

- Blinding Flash
- Crippling Wave(*)
- Seven-Sided-Strike w/ Pandemonium (stun effect)

#### Witch Doctor

- Spirit Walk
- Mass Confusion
- Horrify

#### Demon Hunter

- Smoke Screen
- Shadow Power(*)

Also, having a freeze / stun property on your weapon or any other item also disqualifies you from the achievement. Even a 1% chance counts.

(*): Unsure of these. Have not tested yet.

There might also be more to add (Crusader, anyone?).

Comment: Think it's mass stun or any stun?  For example, Barbarian frenzy with the rune that procs a lightning stun.

Comment: @Troyen I haven't tried it, but I suppose it is any kind of area stun. Whereas SSS-Pandemonium is one stun chance each hit, so I may be proven wrong.

Comment: Does a wizards blizzard with the chance to freeze rune count as cc?

Comment: @z- no idea. I am inclined to say yes,  though. It looks similar to seven sided strike with Pandemonium rune

Comment: What is the crowd control part of diamond skin?

Comment: The definition contains not only CC effect,  but also damage ignoring spells. Mirror image would also be a candidate, in my opinion

Comment: I know Deadly Reach (which has a knockup effect every third strike) is fine, which makes me wonder about Crippling Wave...

Comment: @Bora It would be worth noting in you answer that if your weapon has 1% chance to stun/freeze/fear on hit, that is a sneaky way of not getting the achievement (it counts as CC).

Comment: @diablomonkey have you tested this?

Comment: I have tested the "CC on Weapon", I noticed it about a week ago when playing on Hardcore.  I did not get the achievement several times in a row until I noticed that my weapon had 1.6% chance to freeze.  When I changed weapon I got the achievement.

Comment: I had boots that left a burning trail (Fire Walkers) that prevented me from getting this achievement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide range of skills that will count as crowd control.

First check your gear (including legendary gems) for any of the following:

- Blind
- Charm (eg Deathseer's Cowl) / Confusion
- Cold/Slow/Chill
- Fear
- Freezing
- Immobilize
- Knock Back
- Knock Up
- Polymorph (as in WD chicken)
- Stun

I have no input on the reports of frozen orb working ok, I can first hand confirm that cold damage especially on a weapon counts as CC.

Also any skill that gives those effects will count.

While some skills like a Demon Hunter's Companion with Spiders are clear that it will act as crowd control, some skills have hidden micro-stun effects and are frustrating to detect such as VAULT!

Comment: I got a no CC achievement recently with a templar with three different kinds of crowd control on his weapon/shield. None triggered though, so that seems to be enough. If no CC triggers, it should work.